# Sql update column from column update in single statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a table with 50 columns, lets's say `a,b,c,d` etc.

I want to update b from a and c from the new value of b
,so
`b=b+a,c=c+b ,d = c+ d,..`  etc
I don't want to make an update like
`Update [table] set b=b+a, c= c+b+a..` etc 
because for each column update I must write a huge calculated formula, which will get bigger and more complex for each column.

The table I want to update has about 50 million rows so I think that creating multiple update statements will be a suicide performance wise.

How should I handle this?
Do you think using variables is a good idea?

Thank you and sorry for my English.

*Note: Sorry for not being clear about my question. 
There are 50 new columns in an existing table. 
The first new column, a, is calculated using a join with other tables.
The second new column, b, is calculated by  adding the result to the new value of a, to a calculation I want to make using a join with other tables (the same tables as the first update).
The sames logic applies for calculating the values for all 50 columns.*

Comment: you question is not clear.

Comment: You should have normalized your table, those values belong into another table which is related to this. Then the update and the formula would be easier.

Comment: So how do we know which columns should add up to generate the value of the other column? Is there a relationship that can be derived from the column name? something like column1, column2? Otherwise how can we write a dynamic query or any other query to update each column from a set of other columns which keeps incrementing?

Comment: 50 whole columns - copy, paste, edit

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I edited my original post, I hope its clear now.

Comment: Use OUTER JOINS in your nested logic. JOINS can utilize indexes, which with 50 million rows, you better. xD. For an example, see my updated answer.

Comment: No it is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:**
Thanks for updating your question. Definitely, use `SUBQUERIES` in your `UPDATE` statement to do most of the work. You can utilize `indexes` in your queries through `SARG`s in your `ON`/`WHERE` `predicates`.

Since your logic is self-dependent on the other tables for columns, something like the following will help:

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLE1 (ColA INT, ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) )
INSERT INTO #TABLE1 (ColA ) VALUES (1)
CREATE TABLE #TABLE2 (ColB INT, ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)  )
INSERT INTO #TABLE2 (ColB) VALUES (4)
CREATE TABLE #TABLE3 (ColC INT, ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)  )
INSERT INTO #TABLE3 (ColC) VALUES (10)

SELECT ColC + B.ColB AS ColC, ColC, B.ColB, B.ColA, B.ORIGINAL, B.ID
FROM    #TABLE3 A
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ColB + B.ColA AS ColB, ColA, ORIGINAL, B.ID
                            FROM    #TABLE2 A
                            RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ColA + ColB AS ColA, ColB AS ORIGINAL, A.ID
                                            FROM #TABLE1 A
                                            INNER JOIN #TABLE2 B ON A.ID = B.ID) B ON A.ID = B.ID ) B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Note that for simplicity I just assumed the tables had the same `ID` columns, as I kept the inner `subquery` `ID` in the list. `SQL` goes from right to left (inner queries first), so keep that in mind.

It might be a long series of joins, but at least most of repetitive logic will be handles inside the subqueries themselves. `OUTER JOINS` make sense, since you want to keep the value of the inner query and compare that new computed value with the next outer `subquery`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using update from select like this.

```
    UPDATE T
    SET a = T.a
        ,b = T.b
        ,c = T.c
        ,d = T.d
        ...
        ...
    SELECT a
        ,b = b + a
        ,c = c + b
        ,d = d + c
        ...
        ...
FROM yourtable T
```